# how to make space between looped cards. i use ajax, jquery and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1yfj.png)

there is no space between the cards. how to add a little bit of space between them?

```
.done((todos) => {
        todos.forEach(el => {
            console.log(el)
            $("#todo-list").append(`
             <div class="card col-6 col-sm-4" id="todo-${el.id}" style="width: 18rem; flex-wrap: wrap;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="todo-title">${el.title}</h4>
                        <h6>${el.description}</h6>
                        <p>Due Date: ${el.due_date}</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="updateStatus(${el.id})"> Status</input>
                        <a type="button" class="mw-100 btn-close col position-absolute top-0 end-0" aria-label="Close" id="btn-delete-todo" onclick="deleteTodo(${el.id})"></a>
                        </div>
                </div>
            `)
        })
```

Comment: Look at how it's setting the width; you can set a margin there too. Alternatively, look at adding it in your CSS file

Answer (score 0):

You could use margin, with in the style atrribute or with a bootstrap class.

Using style attribute: `style="margin: 1rem;"`,

```
.done((todos) => {
  todos.forEach(el => {
  console.log(el)
  $("#todo-list").append(`
    <div class="card col-6 col-sm-4" id="todo-${el.id}" style="width: 18rem; margin: 1rem; flex-wrap: wrap;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="todo-title">${el.title}</h4>
        <h6>${el.description}</h6>
        <p>Due Date: ${el.due_date}</p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="updateStatus(${el.id})"> Status</input>
        <a type="button" class="mw-100 btn-close col position-absolute top-0 end-0" aria-label="Close" id="btn-delete-todo" onclick="deleteTodo(${el.id})"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  `)
})
```

Using bootstrap class: `class="m-4"`,

```
.done((todos) => {
  todos.forEach(el => {
  console.log(el)
  $("#todo-list").append(`
    <div class="card col-6 col-sm-4 m-4" id="todo-${el.id}" style="width: 18rem; flex-wrap: wrap;">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="todo-title">${el.title}</h4>
        <h6>${el.description}</h6>
        <p>Due Date: ${el.due_date}</p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="updateStatus(${el.id})"> Status</input>
        <a type="button" class="mw-100 btn-close col position-absolute top-0 end-0" aria-label="Close" id="btn-delete-todo" onclick="deleteTodo(${el.id})"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  `)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this line of code into where you declare the style of the card in where you `append` the card into your `#todo-list`.

It would be something like this:

```
<div class="card col-6 col-sm-4" id="todo-${el.id}" style="width: 18rem;margin-right: .5rem; flex-wrap: wrap;">
```

Alternatively, you can set a `margin-right` or `margin-left` with the value that you actually need to your class `card`.
Moreover, you could even use the default classes for margins if you have Bootstrap 3.
For small, medium and large devices, let's say you can do this:

```
  <div class="card col-6 col-sm-4 mr-1 mr-sm-2 mr-md-2 mr-lg-1" id="todo-${el.id}" style="width: 18rem; flex-wrap: wrap;">
```

I hope my info on the matter can help you.